# edit json data into one object from two

Tags: javascript, json, database

I have this json file stored locally, I want to amend it from this

```
{
    "COUNTRY": "Zimbabwe",
    "SEX": "Female",
    "Value": "61"
}, {
    "COUNTRY": "Zimbabwe",
    "SEX": "Male",
    "Value": "56"
}
```

to this

```
{
    "COUNTRY": "Zimbabwe",
    "Female": "61"
    "Male": "56"
}
```

And thus reduce the amount of repeated rows by putting male and female ages into one COUNTRY object. I don't want to this manually because there are a lot of objects, any ideas? I simply have a json file, no experience with SQL or database coding, but I'm happy to try SQL if I have instructions.

Comment: Loop your JSON object and make map of `COUNTRY` where you append `SEX` as key and `Value` as value. But what if you have two `female: "50"` and `female: "12"` in different sections?

Comment: You want to do it in SQl server side or application server side :

Comment: So, every file on your disk has the same structure shown above, thus two objects on each file? Furthermore, you didn't specify if you need the solution on server or client side? Otherwise, you can't manipulate JSON with SQL if your RDBMS dosn't support it.

Comment: its a locally hosted json file used to print out a table in the html. No SQL, no server side code. I am using a development localhost server to make the page.

Comment: @artworkjpm In case you're still looking for a solution, check my answer below.

Comment: Well, this is a great excuse to begin learning some JavaScript coding, because one way or another _(see good answer below)_ that's what you're going to have to do.  SQL can't help you here.  You must take the JSON, have JS parse it into a JS data structure, manipulate that data-structure and then have JS re-encode it as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this simple solution to accomplish what you're looking for.

```
var X = JSON.parse('[{"COUNTRY": "Zimbabwe","SEX": "Female","Value": "61"},{"COUNTRY": "Zimbabwe","SEX": "Male","Value": "56"}]');
var Y = {};

if(X && typeof X === "object"){
  X.forEach(function(x){
    Y.COUNTRY = x.COUNTRY;
    if(x.SEX.toLowerCase() == "female") Y.FEMALE = x.Value;
    if(x.SEX.toLowerCase() == "male") Y.MALE = x.Value;
  });
}else{
  console.log("JSON Failure!");
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(X, null, 2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(Y, null, 2));
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "COUNTRY": "Zimbabwe",
    "SEX": "Female",
    "Value": "61"
  },
  {
    "COUNTRY": "Zimbabwe",
    "SEX": "Male",
    "Value": "56"
  }
]

{
  "COUNTRY": "Zimbabwe",
  "FEMALE": "61",
  "MALE": "56"
}
```

Working [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/nexufogufe/edit?js,console)